# .scaleAspectFit not working with UIImageView inside Context Menu

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display an image in a `UIImageView` inside a context menu however I am unable to get the content mode of the image view to work.

The `UIImageView` is sized to match the image at 1X, the image I am adding however is sized to the `UIScreen.main.scale` to make it sharper. I have set the mode to `scaleAspectFit` to correctly fit it inside the image view.

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .red
        
        var imageToShow:UIImage = self.arrayImages[cellIndex]
        
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        
        imageToShow = imageToShow.resizeImage(image: imageToShow, targetSize: CGSize(width: (screenSize.width * UIScreen.main.scale), height: (screenSize.height * UIScreen.main.scale)))!
        
        let imageViewSize = CGSize(width: (imageToShow.size.width / UIScreen.main.scale), height: (imageToShow.size.height / UIScreen.main.scale))
      
        // 1
        let imageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageViewSize.width, height: imageViewSize.height))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        imageView.image = imageToShow
        viewController.view = imageView
      
        
        // 2
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      
        // 3
        viewController.preferredContentSize = imageView.frame.size
```

It is almost as if the `.scaleAspectFit` is being ignored as the image never gets sized down to fit into the image view.

This is the image with the scale factor taken into account

[image]

And this is the image without the scale factor taken into account

[image]

**EDIT**

The following is the function i use to resize the image.

```
public func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
            let size = image.size
            
            let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / size.width
            let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height
            
            // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
            var newSize: CGSize
            if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
                newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
            } else {
                newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio, height: size.height * widthRatio)
            }
            
            // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
            let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)
            
            // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
            image.draw(in: rect)
            let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            
            return newImage
        }
```

Comment: Just added the resize function to show how the image is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting this line worked for me:

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

That line removes the constraints on the image view, which causes its position to be ambiguous, and so it is laid out in unexpected ways.

My understanding is that during layout, the image view "expands" to the full image size because it is not constrained in any way, and that is its intrinsic content size. But only since the preferred content size is set to the size before the expansion, only the middle portion of the image is visible.

You can play around with this using Xcode's UI hierarchy debugger. With the above line, you should see that the image view's width & height is bigger than expected, and there is a warning saying that "the image view's position is ambiguous". If you remove the line, the width & height will be as expected, and there is no warning.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have solved the problem. I have spent the morning trying everything else! Also thanks for the explanation. I will take a look at the UI hierarchy debugger